# LightSwitch installation problem

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

A short while ago I tried to install LightSwitch Beta, but after some sizeable and lengthy downloads, the installation aborts after trying to install Silverlight 4.  It simply says that Silverlight 4 could not be installed.  The log is not much help either, as the most informative entries are:

*ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147467260.*

*Return for Microsoft Silverlight 4.0 indicates a failed installation. DepCheck indicates the component is installed.*

*dlmgr: Hash verification failed for Silverlight_Developer.exe.  HRESULT = 0x80091007*

*Error code 1502 for this component means "The event log file is full.*

I am not amazed, and surprisingly I can still be disappointed with a Microsoft installation cock-up, but nonetheless this bugs me.  Mine is a fairly standard dev machine, so why shouldn't something like this just work as expected.  Has anyone encountered a similar situation?  If so, what did you do to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably has to do with your Silverlight version. Check out this thread in the LightSwitch forum for a possible solution.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitchgeneral/thread/3a342a53-0301-49a7-aeb2-71a1254d2f67

HTH,
-Beth