# Unable to install Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-lightswitch

I wanted to give Visual Studio Lightswitch 11 a try with the 90 day trial but I am unable to install it.

I have downloaded the full ISO installer for it from the Microsoft Download site.

The error that the Setup Installer displays is:
Setup could not install the following component:
Microsoft Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 - ENU

The logfiles displays the following:

```
[09/04/11,12:27:43] VS Scenario: [2] Error: CVSScenario::ExecuteEachBlocker returned false
[09/04/11,12:27:43] VS Scenario: [2] Error:There is a blocking condition met, the installer is blocking because of Section :
[09/04/11,12:27:43] VS Scenario: [2] Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional
[09/04/11,12:28:05] VS Scenario: [2] Failed to pass the Warnings/Blocks checks in CVSScenario::Start()
[09/04/11,14:27:18] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[09/04/11,14:27:21] SimpleUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 - ENU is not installed.
[09/04/11,14:39:31] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[09/04/11,14:39:33] SimpleUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 - ENU is not installed.
[09/04/11,19:12:42] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[09/04/11,19:12:44] SimpleUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 - ENU is not installed.
[09/04/11,19:15:41] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[09/04/11,19:15:43] SimpleUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 - ENU is not installed.
[09/04/11,19:43:03] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[09/04/11,19:43:05] SimpleUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 - ENU is not installed.
[09/04/11,20:01:16] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[09/04/11,20:01:18] SimpleUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 - ENU is not installed.
[09/04/11,21:57:41] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[09/04/11,21:57:42] SimpleUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 - ENU is not installed.
[09/05/11,00:26:20] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[09/05/11,00:26:22] SimpleUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 - ENU is not installed.
[09/05/11,00:49:27] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[09/05/11,00:49:29] SimpleUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 - ENU is not installed.
[09/05/11,02:54:59] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[09/05/11,02:55:01] SimpleUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 - ENU is not installed.
[09/05/11,03:07:01] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[09/05/11,03:07:03] SimpleUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 - ENU is not installed.
[09/05/11,10:51:49] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[09/05/11,10:51:51] SimpleUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 - ENU is not installed.
[09/05/11,11:23:12] setup.exe: [2] ISetupComponent::Pre/Post/Install() failed in ISetupManager::InternalInstallManager() with HRESULT -2147023293.
[09/05/11,11:23:14] SimpleUI: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 - ENU is not installed.
```

This is with or without Visual Studio Installed and updated to SP1.

I am currently running Windows 7 Ultimate x64 SP1.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you had a beta version installed previously?

Comment: I only had beta versions of Visual Studio installed, I have since removed Visual Studio to try and troubleshoot the isssue.

Comment: To better clarify - I used the Beta VS2010 Ultimate before it went Final, uninstalled it, then installed the Retail VS2010 Professional with the information I received from Microsoft.  Then just recently wanted to try out LightSwitch 2011 but ran into the installation issues listed above.

Comment: If you do have VS2010 installed, it must have SP1 installed - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2011/07/26/visual-studio-lightswitch-rtm-is-here.aspx

Comment: I've tried with VS2010 SP1 then installing it with the same error and without VS2010 installed at all.  I kind of wished the error was more descriptive.

Comment: You could try http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/07/01/using-msiinv-to-gather-information-about-what-is-installed-on-a-computer.aspx

Comment: Thank You, I am still searching the net for answers on this one though.  I have even ran the stand alone Visual Studio 2010 uninstaller with the same error message.

Comment: This question may be related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899751/lightswitch-installation-problem

Answer (score 0):

I did find a resolution to this issue:
First do a complete backup of the system as the Microsoft Uninstallers will tell you things may not work correctly after running them.

Uninstall of the following using:
Visual Studio 2010 Uninstall Utility 
- http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall
Any remains of .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.
-http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_update/how-to-uninstall-microsoftnet-framework-4-client/a38b6692-cf6f-413f-a903-9a7f7fb44930

Once that was complete any remains of SQL Server or TFS were removed.
Then I proceeded with a fresh install of Visual Studio 2010 and then installed SP1.
After success I installed Visual Studio LightSwitch 2011 from MSDN and the install succeeded.